# Pandas pivot out unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe with two whose combination I consider the unique identifier and then one single column 'C' that can have different values. So the same unique identifier can repeat as many times as the number of different 'C' values it has.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A' : ['000001','000001','000001','000001','000002','000002','000003'],
       'B' : ['1A','1A','1C','1D','1A','1A','1D'],
       'C' : ['003','012','016','003','020','012','053']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

+-------------------+
| A      | B  | C   | 
+-------------------+
| 000001 | 1A | 003 |
| 000001 | 1A | 012 |
| 000001 | 1C | 016 |
| 000001 | 1D | 003 |
| 000002 | 1A | 020 |
| 000002 | 1A | 012 |
| 000003 | 1D | 053 |
+-------------------+
```

I want to group rows based on A, B and then pivot out the C column and turn them into dummies. This is what I need the final output to look like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| A      | B  | C_003 | C_012 | C_016 | C_020 |C_053 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 000001 | 1A | 1     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0    | 
| 000001 | 1C | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0    | 
| 000001 | 1D | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0    | 
| 000002 | 1A | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 0    | 
| 000003 | 1D | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1    | 
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm really bad at pivot tables, but also just not sure if a pivot table can get my to my desired output. I'm looking for a super efficient process, as the actual data has several more columns as part of the identifier (like A, B), thousands of possible C values, and millions of rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.get_dummies` to the rescue.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['A', 'B'])).reset_index()

        A   B  C_003  C_012  C_016  C_020  C_053
0  000001  1A      1      0      0      0      0
1  000001  1A      0      1      0      0      0
2  000001  1C      0      0      1      0      0
3  000001  1D      1      0      0      0      0
4  000002  1A      0      0      0      1      0
5  000002  1A      0      1      0      0      0
6  000003  1D      0      0      0      0      1
```

Or... (thanks Wen for the reminder)

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['A', 'B'])).sum(level=[0, 1]).reset_index()

        A   B  C_003  C_012  C_016  C_020  C_053
0  000001  1A      1      1      0      0      0
1  000001  1C      0      0      1      0      0
2  000001  1D      1      0      0      0      0
3  000002  1A      0      1      0      1      0
4  000003  1D      0      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: The second option seems to be working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and filter all values higher as `1` by [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['A','B', 'C'])
      .size()
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
      .add_prefix('C_')
      .clip_upper(1)
      .reset_index())
print (df)
C       A   B  C_003  C_012  C_016  C_020  C_053
0  000001  1A      1      1      0      0      0
1  000001  1C      0      0      1      0      0
2  000001  1D      1      0      0      0      0
3  000002  1A      0      1      0      1      0
4  000003  1D      0      0      0      0      1
```

Answer (score 3):

You know what I remember my favorite function `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab([df.A,df.B],df.C).reset_index()
Out[70]: 
C       A   B  003  012  016  020  053
0  000001  1A    1    1    0    0    0
1  000001  1C    0    0    1    0    0
2  000001  1D    1    0    0    0    0
3  000002  1A    0    1    0    1    0
4  000003  1D    0    0    0    0    1
```

By using `str` `get_dummies`

```
df.set_index(['A','B']).C.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('C_').sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
Out[60]: 
        A   B  C_003  C_012  C_016  C_020  C_053
0  000001  1A      1      1      0      0      0
1  000001  1C      0      0      1      0      0
2  000001  1D      1      0      0      0      0
3  000002  1A      0      1      0      1      0
4  000003  1D      0      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: I remembered your favorite function too.  Only I put it in my post after you did and I didn't notice it until just now (-:.